# Locate first row number of data set

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to locate the data set I want to filter.  The range is determined by the users input into InputBox.  I want to search column "C" for the ww_from and ww_to. Column "C" is all integers. When I use the code below I can't get the "First" and "Last" variables to load a (x,y) location. Thanks in advance. Scott

```
Public Sub Create_Report()

   'Define range of report
    On Error Resume Next
    ww_from = Application.InputBox _
    ("From what is the workweek do you want to report?")

    ww_to = Application.InputBox _
    (prompt:="To what workweek do you want to report?")


'Select first row of data set locations
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set First = .Column("C").Find(What:="ww_from")

      'Locate data set for report by row number
       k = First.Row
   End With

 'Select last row of data set locations
 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set Last = .Column("C").Cells.Find(What:="ww_to")

End With
         'Case where only one ww is requested in report meaning ww_from = ww_to.
         If l = k Then l = k
         l = Last.Row
```

Comment: *I can't get the "First" and "Last" variables to load* What does this mean? Also, delete the `On Error Resume Next` to see if any error raises that causes your code to fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub Create_Report()


'Define range of report
Dim ww_from As Long
ww_from = Application.InputBox _
    (prompt:="From what is the workweek do you want to report?", Type:=1)

Dim ww_to As Long
ww_to = Application.InputBox _
    (prompt:="To what workweek do you want to report?", Type:=1)


'Select first row of data set locations
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C")
    Dim First As Range
    Set First = .Find(ww_from)
      'Locate data set for report by row number

    Dim k As Long
    If Not First Is Nothing Then k = First.Row

    Dim Last As Range
    Set Last = .Find(ww_to)
    Dim l As Long
    If Not Last Is Nothing Then
        l = Last.Row
    Else
        l = k
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thanks again Scott .  Much appreciated.